# How to automate downloading files from MS Teams + uploading them to Eridoc?

Tags: automation, download, upload, microsoft-teams, uipath

I got a task from my company to research how to automate downloading files from a MS Teams Channel on a certain day of a month and then uploading them to company's Eridoc. Could you please help me with some tips on how to do it?

(Limitation to Python or UiPath would be appreciated to be considered)

Thank you very much in advance for helping.

Comment: What did you try to far. This is an easy process. Where you have issues?

Comment: You can download the Files from teams using graph api could you please Check this [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get-content?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http). Try if that helps.